# How to get local time zone in long form using moment-timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get the current local time zone in moment how to get that?

I used

```
moment.tz.guess(); // It gives "Asia/Calcutta"
```

But I need `India Standard Time`

Answer (score 0):

Using `moment.tz.guess();` you are getting only `zone name` but you are looking for `abbreviation` of `timezone`.

For that you need to use [zoneAbbr()](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/) and find it in your own created **object of abbrs** because moment-timezone does not provide this as stated below in official documentation:

> Moment.js also provides a hook for the long form time zone name.
>   Because these strings are generally localized, **Moment Timezone does
>   not provide any long names for zones**.

[Check here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/) in the documentation for more information.

Below is working code snippet for better understanding:

```js
var zoneName = moment.tz.guess();
console.log(zoneName); // zone name

var timeZoneAbbreviation = moment.tz(zoneName).zoneAbbr()
console.log(timeZoneAbbreviation); // zone abbreviation

var abbrs = {
  EST: 'Eastern Standard Time',
  EDT: 'Eastern Daylight Time',
  CST: 'Central Standard Time',
  CDT: 'Central Daylight Time',
  MST: 'Mountain Standard Time',
  MDT: 'Mountain Daylight Time',
  PST: 'Pacific Standard Time',
  PDT: 'Pacific Daylight Time',
  IST: 'Indian Standard Time',
  JST: 'Japan Standard Time'
};

// using pure JavaScript
var val;
Object.keys(abbrs).forEach(function(timeZoneAbbreviation) {
  val = abbrs[timeZoneAbbreviation];
});
console.log(val); // your expected result


// using lodash.js library
var getKey = function(obj, value) {
  return _.get(obj, value, false);
};

console.log(getKey(abbrs, timeZoneAbbreviation)); // your expected result
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its giving me as "IST", i'm excepting "India Standard Time"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var abbrs = {
    EST : 'Eastern Standard Time',
    EDT : 'Eastern Daylight Time',
    CST : 'Central Standard Time',
    CDT : 'Central Daylight Time',
    MST : 'Mountain Standard Time',
    MDT : 'Mountain Daylight Time',
    PST : 'Pacific Standard Time',
    PDT : 'Pacific Daylight Time',
    IST : 'Indian Standard Time'
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
};

var zone_name =  moment.tz.guess();
var timezone = moment.tz(zone_name).zoneName()
console.log(timezone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

You need to define all full name for abbreviations. For more formatting check [doc](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/).